# How does one setup a Tor hidden service on android

Tags: onion-services, configuration, android

I am looking for some documentation or guide on setting up a Tor hidden service on android, would I just install Tor? Does it torify everything and act like an app. which has a services like nginx or Apache.

Comment: Well in orbot there are settings for hidden services just enable them and fill in the port.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the current beta release of Orbot [15.4.0 beta-2](https://github.com/n8fr8/orbot/releases/tag/15.4.0-beta-2-multi), Orbot has a new menu which makes it very easy to add hidden services.

1. Open settings menu

[image]

2. Click on "Hidden Services"

[image]

3. Click on "Hosted Services"

[image]

4. Pick a name for your service
5. Enter Port your service uses locally
6. Select the port your service is reachable via .onion (choose 80 if it is a web service)

[image]

7. Click on the newly created service in the list
8. Copy the .onion address

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could install orbot and use the following proxy settings.

> SOCKS 4A/5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050
>
> HTTP proxy 127.0.0.1:8118

Answer (score 1):

The first thing if you want to enable a hidden service on your Android phone is that you need Orbot and some application like a webserver or something similar. I assume you have configured a webserver which serves on port 8080.

Now go to the Orbot settings:
[image: Orbot settings for hidden services]

Near the bottom you find the settings for hidden services. Activate the configuration for hidden services (*Hidden Service Hosting*) and click on the entry below (*Hidden Service Ports*). Here you enter the port number of your webserver (8080 in my example). Now close this dialogue and restart Tor. After some time you'll see a green onion again. Go to the settings again and click on *.Onion Hostname*. Now you'll see the name for your hidden service and can use Tor Browser to connect to it.

Comment: The current beta release of Orbot ([Orbot 15.4.0 beta-2](https://github.com/n8fr8/orbot/releases/tag/15.4.0-beta-2-multi)) has a new menu which makes it very easy to add hidden services.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can but only serve one client request at a time due to low bandwidth availability on using third party apps.It isn't secured I can assure you that .Its just a toy to play with , just like JSfiddle tools ,

Download an Android based Kws or Palipa server , config part requires some shell scripting know-hows

Download Or not and Orfox to test the hidden service .

Next Download PhpMyAdmin this part requires some knowledge to create working database and point it while using readymade avail. Scripts like mybb phpbb etc.

Don't forget to configure reachable ports as per u set up earlier

Put this Phpmyadmin in pws folder of Palipa server or